# Is it possible to check if a file stream is open in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io

I have

```
f = File.new(contacts_file_path, "wb")
f.write params[:uploaded_file].read
f.close
```

I want

```
begin
  f = File.new(contacts_file_path, "wb")
  f.write params[:uploaded_file].read
rescue
  #error
ensure
  if f.open? then f.close end
end
```

But f.open? is not a function and I can't find any api documentation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
f.close unless f.closed?
```